# Django admin help text choicefield in tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, django, django-admin

I need to add a specific help-text for each possible value in the choicefield. And I need to show it in a tooltip bubble.

How should I include the value specific help text in the model? and should I use CSS or Javasript tooltip.

I already included helptext in tooltips for other charfields using CSS :hover and adding it in an "extra-admin.css" and this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap-tooltip like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <p>The data-placement attribute specifies the tooltip position.</p>
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Top</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Hooray!">Bottom</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hooray!">Left</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Hooray!">Right</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

you can directly insert this into your Django template for better understanding.

include these scripts

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

anchor with tooltip

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
```

javascript for tooltip

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>
```

these examples are from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had looked into the W3schools website and I understand what you suggested. However I have no idea about how to integrate this into Djanco admin.

Comment: I have Updated my answer please take a look.